# Невозможно подключиться к серверу через WAN

Tags: порты

Поднял на домашней сети сервер Valheim "для своих". Сабж проблемы очень прост: подключиться через WAN невозможно. Зайти из локальной сети могу без каких-либо проблем по указанному порту (192.168.0.108:2456). Да, можно было бы воспользоваться Radmin VPN, но, чёрт побери, проблема гораздо крупнее - у меня и торрент-клиент (uTorrent 1.8.2 -да, устаревший, но работает на другой машине отлично) отказывается нормально функционировать, хотя с ним всё то же самое проделано.

Что имеется:
IP - белый.
Внутренний IP - зарезервирован, 192.168.0.108.
Сервер - поднят и функционирует без ошибок.
Антивирус - отсутствует.

Что делал:
Проброс портов на роутере (и TCP, и UDP) - есть.
Правила для портов и программы в брандмауэре на входящие и исходящие - есть.
Адрес ПК в DMZ закинут - есть.
"netstat -ano" выдаёт порт 2456 без локального адреса и статуса.
Всевозможные манипуляции с брандмауэром (включение/отключение, создание правил в разных состояниях последнего итд) - проделаны.
Драйвера сетевой карты - обновлялись, откатывались, сбрасывались и устанавливались заново.
Запуск сервера - с правами администратора и без, влиять ни на что не должно, но всё же.

Я уже в отчаянии бьюсь двое суток. Магии не бывает, и всё должно работать. Но не работает.